# Loschmidt's paradox - really a paradox?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, arrow-of-time

Is [Loschmidt's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loschmidt%27s_paradox) a paradox even today?

In other words, is the paradox resolved or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19970/2451

Comment: Well, for finite bounded closed systems, there's Poincare recurrences...

Comment: No, it is considered irrelevant today. See, e.g., [this paper](http://fyma.fyma.ucl.ac.be/files/ischia_final.ps.gz). Of course, this does not imply that the problem of the foundations of statistical physics has been settled (in particular, the proper interpretation of probabilities in the theory).

Comment: @YvanVelenik What paper were you referencing? The link is dead.

Comment: @Milan : Well, it was a while ago, so I don't remember. It could be Goldstein's paper in [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-44966-3). But there are other nice papers addressing this topic by Lebowitz or Bricmont for instance (examples: [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/chao-dyn/9603009) and [that one](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Time%27s_arrow_and_Boltzmann%27s_entropy)).

Comment: @YvanVelenik Great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it is not solved. It is based on Boltzmann H-theorem which is highly critical. It is though that the wrong assumption which leads to the paradox is the Stosszahlansatz http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_chaos

Comment: No, the resolution of this "paradox" has nothing to do with the H-theorem. See the refs in my comment above.