# What is the minimum amount of heat created in making a random sequence?

Tags: thermodynamics, information

I was thinking of a random process as: a sequence of random variables whose outcomes do not follow a deterministic pattern, but follow an evolution described by probability distributions.

Given, it is non-deterministic it can be achieved only through processes such as symmetry breaking, collapse of the wave function and hence involve an increase in entropy.

Related: [Does the scientific community consider the Loschmidt paradox resolved? If so what is the resolution?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19970/does-the-scientific-community-consider-the-loschmidt-paradox-resolved-if-so-wha)

My question is what is the minimum amount of heat involved in creating a random sequence of a particular length?

Comment: Is there actually a necessary cost? In symmetry breaking you go from a determinate system (say 0) to one of many possibilities (say $\pm$1); the Landauer principle is fine with that, entropy just increases. Reversing it would cost you $kt\ln(2)$ J.