# Do irreversible processes indicate that time reversible symmetry is a limited phenomenon instead of a universal law?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility, time-reversal-symmetry

Physics and chemistry indicate various [irreversible processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreversible_process), while physics also proposes the theory of [time reversible symmetry (T-symmetry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry). I suppose that evidence of irreversible processes indicates that T-symmetry is a limited phenomenon instead of a universal law, but I also suppose that proponents of T-symmetry have considered the facts of irreversible processes. I answer yes to my question, but I want to learn more about this.

Comment: Thermodynamic irreversibility is a different concept to T-symmetry. Thermodynamic irreversibility is in fact time reversible.

Comment: @John Rennie Could you please elaborate on this? I would be grateful if I could understand how thermodynamic irreversibility is in fact time reversible. I guess I am getting hung up on the semantics. For example, I read that microscopic reversibility is permitted by T-symmetry while all types are reactions are not reversible.

Comment: I think this has been discussed already. I'm just searching the site to see it there is a duplicate question.

Comment: Alternatively we could discuss it [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the scientific community consider the Loschmidt paradox resolved? If so what is the resolution?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19970/)

Comment: See also [Loschmidt's paraox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loschmidt%27s_paradox).